# Display different from Eclipse's browser to Torch's (dropdown no working )

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp, dropdown

I decided to learn jee and I was creating a jsp file but I noticed something really weird, my dropdown works when I display my file on eclipse's internal browser but the drop down doesn't work on Torch or Internet Explorer, I tried to take off everything else to find where does the problem come from; and I found something, first, here's the code if you guys notice something:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false" />
    <jsp:output doctype-root-element="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" omit-xml-declaration="true" />
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" /> script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"/>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
        <div>test</div>
    </body>

    </html>
</jsp:root>
```

ok, the code seems simple and correct for me, but when I try to display it on Torch and I inspect it I find this:

[the problem found in the inspection of the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL4p8.png)

As you may have noticed:

1. The "test" word used to debug isn't showing
2. The script tag isn't closed and it seems like there is the closure of a body tag then the html one?

I've tried adding the into the and I get a blank page on Torch, but still works on eclipse's internal browser.

Guys I feel so stupid like I'm missing something obvious or I don't know, if you have any suggestion, as obvious as you may think go ahead and say it please :D

P.S: I've taught of encoding problems but how would I check that ?

Comment: anyone please? halp :'(

Comment: Looks like you asked the same thing just a few hours earlier at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620361/display-different-from-eclipses-browser-to-torchs-dropdowns . When you're displaying it in Torch or the internal browser, are by running it within a server?

Comment: yes, i'm new here so i taught i'd ask again in case someone didn't see it, anyways i found the solution, weird as it is , i added a comment between the <script> and the </script>, any sort of comment will do !